# Android Service doesn't Stop running

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I create a service and put it in the foreground with a notification. In the service I have a timer that just prints "SERVICE STILL RUNNING"  to let me know the service is still alive. When I close the app, the OnDestroy() of the service is called but the timmer keeps printing "SERVICE STILL RUNNING" why is that? I put the service in the foreground by calling showNotification(). If I don't call showNotification() and close the app the service  gets destroyed and the timmer stops printing "SERVICE STILL RUNNING". How can I have the service in the foreground and kill it correctly when the app is closed. The memory monitor continues to show the memory usage even after the app is closed. If I dont put the service in the foreground and close the app, the memory monitor stops.This problem only happens and android 6.0.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Intent service;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        service = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class);

        // starting Client service
        service.setAction("START");
        startService(service);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        service.setAction("STOP");
        stopService(service);
    }
}
```

Service:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    Timer timer;




    public MyService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       //return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        if(intent !=null)
        {
            if(intent.getAction().equals("START"))
            {

               showNotification();
            } else if(intent.getAction().equals("STOP"))
            {
                stopForeground(true);
                stopSelf();

            }
        }else
        {
            //stopForeground(true);
            //stopSelf();

        }




        return START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {


                Log.d("","SERVICE STILL RUNNING");

            }
        },1*1000,5*1000);
    }

    private void showNotification() {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setAction("new");
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);


        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setTicker("Test")
                .setContentText("testing")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon, 128, 128, false))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setOngoing(true).build();

        startForeground(101, notification);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("","SERVICE HAS BEEN DESTROYED!!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Service Binding with your Activity http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/components/bound-services.html

Comment: @zgc7009-Can I put a bound service in the foreground with a notification so the Android OS wont kill the service?

Comment: Have you looked at http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Service.html and it's "Local Service" section where it talks about notifications?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this on you Service's onDestroy

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    timer.cancel();
    timer = null;
    stopForeground(true);//Add this. Since stopping a service in started in foreground is different from normal services.
    Log.d("","SERVICE HAS BEEN DESTROYED!!!");
}
```

**EDIT**

On your Activity's onDestroy method

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    service.setAction("STOP");
    service.executeStopForeground();
    stopService(service);
}
```

Then add this method on your service:

```
public void executeStopForeground()
{
    stopForeground(true);
}
```

Comment: @ljpv14- yes, this will stop the timer but it still doesnt stop the service. Any idea why the memory monitor continues to work?

Comment: Can you show me exactly what does your memory monitor shows after the service gets destroyed?

Comment: @ljpv14- It just contines to plot the memory usage. The amount of memory allocated drop a bit then stays constant. the memory monitor stops when I go into settings for the app and press "Force Stop"

Comment: I think because your service is using START_STICKY onStartCommand. Try using START_NOT_STICKY. Since you're already starting your service on foreground. You don't have to set is as START_STICKY.  If it still persists, I'm honestly not sure what other things may cause this. Don't lose hope! That's all the help I can give.

Comment: @ljpv14- I tried  START_NOT_STICKY it still doesnt work. Thanks for trying

Comment: I refuse to give up on you. Lol. See my edited post. I have added stopForeground(true); on your Service's onDestroy.

Comment: @ljpv14- I tired that too lol. It seems that it only works if I call  stopForeground(true) before I try to close the app. Calling  stopForeground(true) in the Ondestroy() method in the activity or service does not work

Comment: See my edited post. That's the only thing I could think of. Lol. Call stopForeground by using your service object before your application gets destroyed.

Comment: @ljpv14- I tried that also, still doesnt work, Any idea why this only happens on android 6.0

Comment: In my tests this only happens on samsung devices with android 6.x and 4.4.2, other devices dont have this behavior

Answer (score 0):

Use inside your service code:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stopForeground(true);
    super.onDestroy();
    System.exit(0); //We terminate the app!
}
```